# Why this 'useless use of cat' with `detex` is 10x faster than the alternative?

Tags: bash, shell, cat, time, latex

I'm counting words in LaTeX files and intuitively used the command:

```
$ cat *tex | detex | wc -w
```

I then immediately noticed he [useless use of `cat`](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat), and did the task again with:

```
$ detex *tex | wc -w
```

Being proud of myself for avoiding an extra process, I wanted to check how many precious milliseconds I saved by not using `cat`. I was then very surprised to see that the version *with* `cat` was literally 10 times faster:

```
$ time cat *tex | detex | wc -w
    5000

real    0m0.013s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.007s
```

```
$ time detex *tex | wc -w
    5000

real    0m0.144s
user    0m0.124s
sys 0m0.014s
```

What is the reason for this massive speed difference? Is `cat` just so much faster in reading files from a disk than `detex`?

---

I generated 5 example "LaTeX" files for benchmarking with:

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do shuf -n 1000 /usr/share/dict/words > "file${i}.tex"; done
```

Comment: One possibility I feel likely is that `detex` reinitializes some costly setup after each file, while cat assembles them all into a single stream which is detexed only once.

Comment: `strace`ing `detex` (from texlive on Arch Linux) in the two cases shows that, when invoked with arguments, it opens and reads several files (several `ls-R`, `texmf.cnf`, `texmf`, `texmf-dist`) that are not open when it reads from standard input. Though I have no clue on the reason.

Comment: What version of `detex` are you using? This is presumably related to Kpathsea but I don’t reproduce it on Debian 10.

Comment: You may want to check that the result from the two ways of running `detex` are identical.  Note also that the `detex` manual says `Running LaTeX source without a ``\begin{document}'' through detex may produce errors.`,  so since your "test data" isn't actual TeX or LaTeX input, I would be wary about interpreting any timing results.

Comment: @Kusalananda I tested first with 5 actual LaTeX documents which had around 8000 words in total. The results were the same. These dummy files were just for others to use. But good to know!

Comment: @StephenKitt using `$ detex -v` gives the output: `OpenDetex version 2.8.5 https://github.com/pkubowicz/opendetex`

Comment: I've installed it from MacTeX.

Comment: The problem here: The results highly depend on caching and the timing in the Linux kernel is not very accurate. I recommend to run the commands at least 10 times and use the lowest values. I did run a similar test with a program different fro detex and the results on Solaris (using bosh instead of bash) are very similar. The Solaris kernel implements micro state accounting...

Comment: I may have been confusing: correct is that the timing results of the variant with and without `cat` are similar on Solaris and there is less variation between repeated calls on Solaris because of the micro state accounting on Solaris. `bosh` is furthermore better for such tests because it pemits one microsecond granularity with the right `TIMEFORMAT` einvironment (see man page). My conclusion is that the reporter did not identify a real proof for cat makes things faster.

Comment: @Kusalananda The results were the same, `$ diff <(cat *tex | detex) <(detex *tex)` gives no diff. But I posted an answer where I show that my initial results were just noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial results seem to just be an inconsistency.

Installed the latest `detex` from [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/opendetex):

```
$ detex -v

OpenDetex version 2.8.9
https://github.com/pkubowicz/opendetex
```

Got an example LaTeX file:

```
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/latex3/latex3/main/articles/2011-current-state.tex > file.tex
```

Made 100 copies of the file:

```
$ for i in {1..100}; do cp file.tex "file${i}.tex"; done
```

Ran the `cat` version 5 times:

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do time cat *tex | detex | wc -w; done
   78174

real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.025s
sys 0m0.012s
   78174

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.023s
sys 0m0.009s
   78174

real    0m0.019s
user    0m0.020s
sys 0m0.008s
   78174

real    0m0.019s
user    0m0.019s
sys 0m0.008s
   78174

real    0m0.017s
user    0m0.018s
sys 0m0.008s
```

Ran the non-`cat` version 5 times:

```
$ for i in {1..5}; do time detex *tex | wc -w; done
   78174

real    0m0.027s
user    0m0.023s
sys 0m0.009s
   78174

real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.021s
sys 0m0.007s
   78174

real    0m0.021s
user    0m0.020s
sys 0m0.005s
   78174

real    0m0.019s
user    0m0.017s
sys 0m0.005s
   78174

real    0m0.018s
user    0m0.016s
sys 0m0.005s
```